# Show empty records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form on which I have a multiselect for different boxes and for boxes there exists some records i-e (the number of openings of the box) in the database but it might be possible that for a selected box no records exists ie (the box is not opened even single time). Currently when I select different boxes and if records does not exist for a box it does not return the empty array for that box  I want to it return even the empty results for the selected box. My query is

```
public function getBoxOpenings($boxes, $from_date, $to_date){
$query = $this->db->select('box_id, COUNT(box_id) AS Openings')
    ->from('boxes')
    ->where_in('box_id', $boxes)
    ->where('actiontime >=', $from_date)
    ->where('actiontime <=', $to_date)
    ->group_by('box_id')
    ->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
return $data;
}
```

If I select 3 boxes and submit the form and records exists for only 2 boxes it returns something like this

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 12
        [location] => FRA-Air
        [Openings] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 14
        [location] => FRA-Hof
        [Openings] => 1
    )

)
```

How can I get all three records with one empty like this

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 16
        [location] => Test
        [Openings] => 
    )
```

How Can I get the records for all the selected boxes with empty arrays for those which have no records.

Thanks

Comment: is the query returning empty or NULL???

Comment: it just simply ignore the box for which no results are returned

Comment: I would love to help you but I don't get what you need

Comment: @jcho360 I have a mutiselect tag on my form, from which I select different options let say I select 3 options (the options are called boxes) and in my database table I have the number of openings for boxes, but it is possible that the boxes i selected from select drop down may contain a box with no openings and hence no data in the table, what I want is to that my query returns me the result of that selection as well with openings = 0, Hope it clarify somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is obvious: You only insert a row into that table when the box is opened by user. If the box not opened ever that table contains no record for that box.

If You then do a `select * from table where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` but Your table contains only rows for ids 2 and 3, the result set will contain only the data for the ids 2 and 3 as there are no records found for other ids.

I guess You only could call this query in a loop for each `$box_id` from `$boxes` - when the data is found return it otherwise return zero. Like this:

```
public function getBoxOpenings($boxes, $from_date, $to_date){
    $data = array();
    foreach($boxes as $box) {
        $query = $this->db->select('box_id, COUNT(box_id) AS Openings')
            ->from('boxes')
            ->where('box_id = ', $box)
            ->where('actiontime >= ', $from_date)
            ->where('actiontime <= ', $to_date)
            ->group_by('box_id')
            ->get();
        $res = $query->result_array();
        if($res)
            $data[] = $res;
        else
            $data[] = array('box_id' => $box, 'Openings' => 0);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

But this is not very nice as You do one query per each box that will be very resource consuming when having a lot of boxes...

Comment: it looks like your solution will work... I will give it a try soon... thanks for the reply

Comment: If i select two boxes in which for one entries are available and not for the other it runs the query two times and give the result of only the box which contains records

Comment: Print out `$res` after the `$res = $query->result_array();` call to see what it returns when there is no result. Change the `if($res)` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot man it works now... but i have to think about the performance issue as you mentioned, because to get the location of the box i have to add one another query and if the number of boxes increases it will definitely affect the performance... but I highly appreciate your help... Thank you so much :)